# how to get the build mode in vs 2008 in c++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have an mfc program where I want to do some functions in the release mode of the program only. How can I find the build mode(whether its release mode or debug mode) by using the code inside the program? I am using vs 2008 version.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following preprocessor directive to find out if you are in debug mode.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG

#endif
```

For release, use `#ifndef`.

All code inside these blocks will only be compiled and executed if the correct mode is set.